# How to convert string into int and give back 0 when it is null in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I substracted 1 field, which is a string, into 2 fields.
The first field exists of the 1st series of numbers.
The second field exists of everything that comes after the 1st series of numbers.

The first field must be converted to an int.
And the second field, which is a string, must gives a 0 when it is null.

For example:

95A3 would be an int 95 and a string A3

242 C2 would be an int 242 and a string C2

367 would be an int 367 and a 0

26 would be an int 26 and a 0

This is the query I have thusfar:

```
select 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '\d+') NUMBERS, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '[a-zA-Z].*.') EVERYTHINGAFTERNUMBERS
from DATAVIEW
```

Comment: Hint: COALESCE() or NVL()...

Comment: I'd chose COALESCE(), since it is ANSI SQL and portable.

Comment: How can I implement this with my excisting query?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by this?  Tell us the bigger picture please.  What is the end result supposed to be?  Then read up on COALESCE and NVL and give it a try and update your post with results.

Answer (score 3):

You would do:

```
select cast(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '\d+') as int) as num, 
       coalesce(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '[a-zA-Z].*.'), '0') EVERYTHINGAFTERNUMBERS
from DATAVIEW;
```

Note that the second `coalesce()` is returning `'0'`, not `0`.  A single column cannot be both a string and a number.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has two famous functions `nvl` for converting a null value to a fixed value, and `to_number` for casting a string value as a numeric value. So,

```
select to_number(NUMBERS) as numbers,
       nvl(EVERYTHINGAFTERNUMBERS,'0') as everythingafternumbers
  from
  (
    with DATAVIEW(DATA) as
    (
     select '95A3' from dual union all    
     select '242C2' from dual union all 
     select '367' from dual union all
     select '26' from dual   
    )
    select REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '\d+') NUMBERS, 
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '[a-zA-Z].*.') EVERYTHINGAFTERNUMBERS
      from DATAVIEW
   ) 

NUMBERS  EVERYTHINGAFTERNUMBERS
   95             A3
  242             C2
  367              0
   26              0
```

might be considered.